# How to get all objects and count booleans (JS)

Tags: javascript, object, count, boolean

Let it be like this for example:

```
let data = {
    first: {
        surname: 'Miller',
        age: 37,
        gender: 'male',
        stealer: true
    },
    second: {
        surname: 'Connor',
        age: 28,
        gender: 'male',
        stealer: true
    },
    third: {
        surname: 'Smith',
        age: 13,
        gender: 'female',
        stealer: false
    }
}
```

How can I get everything at once and count booleans of false, without the need to manually enter each one individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to retrieve the values as an array and `Array.prototype.reduce` to count:

```js
let data = { first: { surname: 'Miller', age: 37, gender: 'male', stealer: true }, second: { surname: 'Connor', age: 28, gender: 'male', stealer: true }, third: { surname: 'Smith', age: 13, gender: 'female', stealer: false } };

const result = Object.values(data).flatMap(el => Object.values(el)).reduce((acc, el) => acc + (el === false), 0); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me.